# How to plus elements in array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Like these python below

```
[m + n for m in 'ABC' for n in 'XYZ']
>>> ['AX', 'AY', 'AZ', 'BX', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ']
```

How to archive it in ruby in one line?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one using [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-product) and [`Array#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
'ABC'.chars.product('XYZ'.chars).map(&:join)
#=> ["AX", "AY", "AZ", "BX", "BY", "BZ", "CX", "CY", "CZ"]
```

Comment: nice one, less block.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby one way of doing this is:

```
'ABC'.chars.flat_map { |a| 'XYZ'.chars.map { |b| a + b } }
# => ["AX", "AY", "AZ", "BX", "BY", "BZ", "CX", "CY", "CZ"]
```